# Regex sub returns None

Tags: python, regex, jsonpath

So I am working with this program which takes a JSON mapper input and then proceeds to make data from a source.
We are importing stock data, however sometimes we receive something like 50+.

Using the jsonpath-ng library another developer made the following mapper, including a sub to remove unwanted '+' characters, since we don't want those.

```
{"quantity": "$..Stock.`sub(/\\\\+/, \\)`", "article_code": "$..Barcode"}
```

The issue I am running into is that it works fine when we receive a quantity like 50+, it converts it just fine to 50, but when we receive something like 3, then it converts it to None. I can't seems to find a way to prevent values without a '+' from being converted to None.

Does anyone know how to change it so that it removes a '+' if found, and if not found just let it be instead of changing it to None?

Comment: `?` in regex signifies the character following `?` is optional.It might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears a [deliberate decision in jsonpath-ng](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng/blob/6b8ec143cf3eda4895dcf4c259a2face94626f7a/jsonpath_rw/ext/string.py#L42) that if the `sub` does not change anything, the item is converted to `None`.  I find this rather puzzling.

As a workaround, you could append a `+` at the end of the string and *then* rewrite it with `sub`, which will now always modify it, not producing `None`.

Comment: Thanks, I find it puzzling as well. I tried what you suggested, and it seems like it worked.